# Logitech LED Illumination SDK Permanent Color change

Tags: c#, logitech, logitech-gaming-software, logitech-led-illumination-sdk

I have a simple console application that mutes the microphone. I'd like to change the color of a single key when this application runs once. Once it ran and the microphone is muted, color of the key changes. Once it ran again, and the microphone is unmuted, color is back to normal.

I got the color of the key to change, but once the application finishes and closes, the color switches back to what it was, i assume this is thanks to the fact that the Logitech LED Illumination SDK closes, but i might be wrong.

I'd like to change the color of the key once the console application ran, and keep this change, even after the application finishes running. Is this possible in a Console application that only runs once, when a hotkey is pressed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logitech LED SDK keeps your changes while the library is connected (between `LogiLedInit` and `LogiLedShutdown`).
So, you must keep your application running to persist the color of the key.
You may create a window-less application for this purpose.  Or a console application may keep running in the background after closing the console window.